# find minimum variance unbiased estimator

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-programming

**Question**

Suppose that the random variables $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are such that

$\quad E(Y_j)=\mu, var(Y_j) = \sigma^2, cov(Y_j,Y_k) = \rho \sigma_j\sigma_k$

where $\mu$ is unknown and the $\sigma_j^2$'s and $\rho$ are known.

Consider the linear combination estimator $Y_L$ of the $Y_j$'s giving an unbiased estimator of $\mu$. Find its minimum variance and the optimal weight.

**Here is my idea**:

Let $Y_L = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j$, and since $Y_L$ is unbiased of $\mu$, we find $E(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n \mu = \mu$, i.e.,

$\quad\sum_{j=1}^n a_j = 1$

and the variance of $Y_L$ is

$\quad var(Y_L) =var(\sum_{j=1}^n a_jY_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2\sigma_j^2 + \sum_{j\neq i}\rho a_ia_j\sigma_i\sigma_j$

and then define the Lagrangian

$L = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2\sigma_j^2 + \sum_{j\neq i}\rho a_ia_j\sigma_i\sigma_j - \lambda(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j - 1)$

use the usual way to find the minimum variance.

However, I don't know how to solve this Lagrangian.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2\sigma_j^2 + \sum_{j\neq i}\rho_{ij} a_ia_j\sigma_i\sigma_j$ can be written with the variance-covariance matrix $C$. I indexed the correlation coefficients in order to distinguish between them. It is $a^TCa$, where $a^T=\begin{pmatrix}{}a_1,a_2,...,a_n \end{pmatrix}$ Therefore your Langarian becomes

$$\mathcal L=a^TCa+\lambda\left(1-u^Ta \right)$$

with $u^T=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{}1,1,...,1 \end{pmatrix}}_{\text{n-times}}$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial a}=2Ca-\lambda u=0 \qquad (1)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda}=1-u^Ta=0 \qquad (2)$

Solving (1) for a gives $a=\frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot C^{-1}\cdot u$. Plugging in the term for $a$ in (2).

$1-u^T\cdot \frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot C^{-1}\cdot u =0 $

$\lambda=\frac2{u^T\cdot C^{-1}\cdot u }$

$s=u^T\cdot C^{-1}\cdot u$ is a scalar. Thus $s^{-1}=\frac1s$

Now we use (1) again to calculate $a^*$

$2Ca=\frac2{u^T\cdot C^{-1}\cdot u } u$

$\boxed{a^*=\frac{C^{-1}\cdot u}{u^T\cdot C^{-1}\cdot u}}$